# pthread function from a class

Tags: c++, pthreads

Let's say I have a class such as

```
class c { 
    // ...
    void *print(void *){ cout << "Hello"; }
}
```

And then I have a vector of c

```
vector<c> classes; pthread_t t1;
classes.push_back(c());
classes.push_back(c());
```

Now, I want to create a thread on `c.print();`

And the following is giving me the problem below:

`pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &c[0].print, NULL);`

> Error Output: cannot convert ‘void* (tree_item::*)(void*)’ to ‘void*
> (*)(void*)’  for argument ‘3’ to ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const
> pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can't do it the way you've written it because C++ class member functions have a hidden `this` parameter passed in.  `pthread_create()` has no idea what value of `this` to use, so if you try to get around the compiler by casting the method to a function pointer of the appropriate type, you'll get a segmetnation fault.  You have to use a static class method (which has no `this` parameter), or a plain ordinary function to bootstrap the class:

```
class C
{
public:
    void *hello(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    static void *hello_helper(void *context)
    {
        return ((C *)context)->hello();
    }
};
...
C c;
pthread_t t;
pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, &c);
```

Comment: would the above work with vectors in the following way:
pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, &vector_c[0]);
?

Comment: All the above comments are usefull i used a combination from all to solve an issue.. It still dosent does as simple as i was trying to do it... But unfortunatlly i can only mark one as being the correct, Otherwise every one gets the credit..Thanks

Comment: I wanted to upvote this answer, but it uses C-style casts, which must be terminated with extreme prejudice. This answer is otherwise correct.

Comment: @Chris: I don't want to get into a holy war about cast styles, but it's perfectly semantically correct to use a C-style cast in this instance.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield it's also perfectly semantically correct to chain adverbs together, but that doesn't make it good style!  xD

Comment: may this answer be wrong in any sense? see the comments by [Loki Astari](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14065/loki-astari) to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11528833/1025391).

Comment: @moooeeeep: Yes, technically the static method should be declared `extern "C"` to be 100% portable, but virtually every compiler in existence uses the same calling convention for `static` class methods as for `extern "C"` functions.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Not true. If you only count main stream compilers G++/MSVC etc then you get 100%. When you get off the beaten track the numbers drop away quickly. **BUT** that is not the point: non portable code is non portable however you look at it one day it will break and finding the problem will be next to imposable (such is the joy of non portable code).

Comment: Great answer, except I ran into compile errors on G++ (4.7). To fix them, I removed the return statement from the helper (hello_helper) method.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield : I have worked on similar implementation where I used in `pthread_create(&this->thread, NULL, this->functionPointer, NULL);`.  Here `functionPointer` is a class member & and a pointer to a normal function is assigned to this pointer upon each object instantiation. and later it is passed as `this->functionPointer` to `pthread_create` as an argument. And surprisingly, it works. You can see the code here: [link]http://paste.ofcode.org/ETKUd2LS8XejYtskmDwBeu .You said `pthread_create` has no idea what `this` is. So,can u explain how `this` is working here?

Comment: @Rohit: Your thread procedure `threadOne()` never tries to do anything with its argument `args`.  If it did, it would get `NULL`, and it would be unable to access the `Thread` object instance.  What's surprising there?

Comment: Suppose I put pthread_create in some member function and I create multiple instance of class C. If I call member function with pthread_create, would there be thread created for each instance?. In pthread_create i would call routine as per helper function as described.

Answer (score 86):

My favorite way to handle a thread is to encapsulate it inside a C++ object.  Here's an example:

```
class MyThreadClass
{
public:
   MyThreadClass() {/* empty */}
   virtual ~MyThreadClass() {/* empty */}

   /** Returns true if the thread was successfully started, false if there was an error starting the thread */
   bool StartInternalThread()
   {
      return (pthread_create(&_thread, NULL, InternalThreadEntryFunc, this) == 0);
   }

   /** Will not return until the internal thread has exited. */
   void WaitForInternalThreadToExit()
   {
      (void) pthread_join(_thread, NULL);
   }

protected:
   /** Implement this method in your subclass with the code you want your thread to run. */
   virtual void InternalThreadEntry() = 0;

private:
   static void * InternalThreadEntryFunc(void * This) {((MyThreadClass *)This)->InternalThreadEntry(); return NULL;}

   pthread_t _thread;
};
```

To use it, you would just create a subclass of MyThreadClass with the InternalThreadEntry() method implemented to contain your thread's event loop.  You'd need to call WaitForInternalThreadToExit() on the thread object before deleting the thread object, of course (and have some mechanism to make sure the thread actually exits, otherwise WaitForInternalThreadToExit() would never return)

Comment: That is a great way i can understand the use of the above Virtual Class, But i have much deaper problems..I have threads that spawn off other threads that need to be all put in a vector. And then a recursive loop to go and join all the threads. Im sure i could implement the above to do that as well by calling the wait in the proper place, But il try it to see where i get to

Comment: This solution is so very elegant. I will use it from now on. Thank you Jeremy Friesner. +1

Comment: hello Jeremy Friesner, how to pass a reference to InternalThreadEntry(aclass_ref& refobj) ? what changes I should make?

Comment: @sree Add the reference (or a pointer) to the MyThreadClass as a member variable; then InternalThreadEntry() can access it directly, without having to worry about passing it via the (void *) argument.

Answer (score 10):

You'll have to give `pthread_create` a function that matches the signature it's looking for. What you're passing won't work.

You can implement whatever static function you like to do this, and it can reference an instance of `c` and execute what you want in the thread. `pthread_create` is designed to take not only a function pointer, but a pointer to "context". In this case you just pass it a pointer to an instance of `c`.

For instance:

```
static void* execute_print(void* ctx) {
    c* cptr = (c*)ctx;
    cptr->print();
    return NULL;
}


void func() {

    ...

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, execute_print, &c[0]);

    ...
}
```

Comment: ooo i see what you mean.. pass it the pointer of c, gotcha.. will implement and try it out

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are good, but in my case, 1st approach that converts the function to be a static didn't work. I was trying to convert exiting code to move into thread function but that code had lots to references to non-static  class members already. The second solution of encapsulating into C++ object works, but has 3-level wrappers to run a thread.

I had an alternate solution that uses existing C++ construct - 'friend' function, and it worked perfect for my case.
An example of how I used 'friend' (will use the above same example for names showing how it can be converted into a compact form using friend)

```
    class MyThreadClass
    {
    public:
       MyThreadClass() {/* empty */}
       virtual ~MyThreadClass() {/* empty */}

       bool Init()
       {
          return (pthread_create(&_thread, NULL, &ThreadEntryFunc, this) == 0);
       }

       /** Will not return until the internal thread has exited. */
       void WaitForThreadToExit()
       {
          (void) pthread_join(_thread, NULL);
       }

    private:
       //our friend function that runs the thread task
       friend void* ThreadEntryFunc(void *);

       pthread_t _thread;
    };

    //friend is defined outside of class and without any qualifiers
    void* ThreadEntryFunc(void *obj_param) {
    MyThreadClass *thr  = ((MyThreadClass *)obj_param); 

    //access all the members using thr->

    return NULL;
    }
```

Ofcourse, we can use boost::thread and avoid all these, but I was trying to modify the C++ code to not use boost (the code was linking against boost just for this purpose)

Answer (score 1):

My first answer ever in the hope that it'll be usefull to someone :
I now this is an old question but I encountered exactly the same error as the above question as I'm writing a TcpServer class and I was trying to use pthreads. I found this question and I understand now why it was happening. I ended up doing this:

```
#include <thread>
```

method to run threaded -> `void* TcpServer::sockethandler(void* lp) {/*code here*/}`

and I call it with a lambda -> `std::thread( [=] { sockethandler((void*)csock); } ).detach();`

that seems a clean approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

Too many times I've found ways to solve what you are asking for that, in my opinion are too complicated. 
For instance you have to define new class types, link library etc. 
So I decided to write a few lines of code that allow the end user 
to basically be able to "thread-ize" a "void ::method(void)" of whatever class.
For sure this solution I implemented can be extended, improved etc, so, 
if you need more specific methods or features, add them and please be so kind to keep me in the loop.

Here are 3 files that show what I did.

```
    // A basic mutex class, I called this file Mutex.h
#ifndef MUTEXCONDITION_H_
#define MUTEXCONDITION_H_

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class MutexCondition
{
private:
    bool init() {
        //printf("MutexCondition::init called\n");
        pthread_mutex_init(&m_mut, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&m_con, NULL);
        return true;
    }

    bool destroy() {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_mut);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&m_con);
        return true;
    }

public:
    pthread_mutex_t m_mut;
    pthread_cond_t m_con;

    MutexCondition() {
        init();
    }
    virtual ~MutexCondition() {
        destroy();
    }

    bool lock() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mut);
        return true;
    }

    bool unlock() {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mut);
        return true;
    }

    bool wait() {
        lock();
        pthread_cond_wait(&m_con, &m_mut);
        unlock();
        return true;
    }

    bool signal() {
        pthread_cond_signal(&m_con);
        return true;
    }
};
#endif
// End of Mutex.h
```

// The class that incapsulates all the work to thread-ize a method (test.h):

```
#ifndef __THREAD_HANDLER___
#define __THREAD_HANDLER___

#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Mutex.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
class CThreadInfo
{
  public:
    typedef void (T::*MHT_PTR) (void);
    vector<MHT_PTR> _threaded_methods;
    vector<bool> _status_flags;
    T *_data;
    MutexCondition _mutex;
    int _idx;
    bool _status;

    CThreadInfo(T* p1):_data(p1), _idx(0) {}
    void setThreadedMethods(vector<MHT_PTR> & pThreadedMethods)
    {
        _threaded_methods = pThreadedMethods;
      _status_flags.resize(_threaded_methods.size(), false);
    }
};

template <class T> 
class CSThread {
  protected:
    typedef void (T::*MHT_PTR) (void);
    vector<MHT_PTR> _threaded_methods;
    vector<string> _thread_labels;
    MHT_PTR _stop_f_pt;
    vector<T*> _elements;
    vector<T*> _performDelete;
    vector<CThreadInfo<T>*> _threadlds;
    vector<pthread_t*> _threads;
    int _totalRunningThreads;

    static void * gencker_(void * pArg)
    {
      CThreadInfo<T>* vArg = (CThreadInfo<T> *) pArg;
      vArg->_mutex.lock();
      int vIndex = vArg->_idx++;
      vArg->_mutex.unlock();

      vArg->_status_flags[vIndex]=true;

      MHT_PTR mhtCalledOne = vArg->_threaded_methods[vIndex];
      (vArg->_data->*mhtCalledOne)();
      vArg->_status_flags[vIndex]=false;
        return NULL;
    }

  public:
    CSThread ():_stop_f_pt(NULL), _totalRunningThreads(0)  {}
    ~CSThread()
    {
      for (int i=_threads.size() -1; i >= 0; --i)
          pthread_detach(*_threads[i]);

      for (int i=_threadlds.size() -1; i >= 0; --i)
        delete _threadlds[i];

      for (int i=_elements.size() -1; i >= 0; --i)
         if (find (_performDelete.begin(), _performDelete.end(), _elements[i]) != _performDelete.end())
              delete _elements[i];
    }
    int  runningThreadsCount(void) {return _totalRunningThreads;}
    int  elementsCount()        {return _elements.size();}
    void addThread (MHT_PTR p, string pLabel="") { _threaded_methods.push_back(p); _thread_labels.push_back(pLabel);}
    void clearThreadedMethods() { _threaded_methods.clear(); }
    void getThreadedMethodsCount() { return _threaded_methods.size(); }
    void addStopMethod(MHT_PTR p)  { _stop_f_pt  = p; }
    string getStatusStr(unsigned int _elementIndex, unsigned int pMethodIndex)
    {
      char ch[99];

      if (getStatus(_elementIndex, pMethodIndex) == true)
        sprintf (ch, "[%s] - TRUE\n", _thread_labels[pMethodIndex].c_str());
      else 
        sprintf (ch, "[%s] - FALSE\n", _thread_labels[pMethodIndex].c_str());

      return ch;
    }
    bool getStatus(unsigned int _elementIndex, unsigned int pMethodIndex)
    {
      if (_elementIndex > _elements.size()) return false;
      return _threadlds[_elementIndex]->_status_flags[pMethodIndex];
    }

    bool run(unsigned int pIdx) 
    {
      T * myElem = _elements[pIdx];
      _threadlds.push_back(new CThreadInfo<T>(myElem));
      _threadlds[_threadlds.size()-1]->setThreadedMethods(_threaded_methods);

      int vStart = _threads.size();
      for (int hhh=0; hhh<_threaded_methods.size(); ++hhh)
          _threads.push_back(new pthread_t);

      for (int currentCount =0; currentCount < _threaded_methods.size(); ++vStart, ++currentCount)
      {
                if (pthread_create(_threads[vStart], NULL, gencker_, (void*) _threadlds[_threadlds.size()-1]) != 0)
        {
                // cout <<"\t\tThread " << currentCount << " creation FAILED for element: " << pIdx << endl;
                    return false;
                }
        else
        {
            ++_totalRunningThreads;
             // cout <<"\t\tThread " << currentCount << " creation SUCCEDED for element: " << pIdx << endl;
                }
      }
      return true;
    }

    bool run() 
    {
            for (int vI = 0; vI < _elements.size(); ++vI) 
            if (run(vI) == false) return false;
          // cout <<"Number of currently running threads: " << _totalRunningThreads << endl;
        return true;
    }

    T * addElement(void)
    {
      int vId=-1;
      return addElement(vId);
    }

    T * addElement(int & pIdx)
    {
      T * myElem = new T();
      _elements.push_back(myElem);
      pIdx = _elements.size()-1;
      _performDelete.push_back(myElem);
      return _elements[pIdx];
    }

    T * addElement(T *pElem)
    {
      int vId=-1;
      return addElement(pElem, vId);
    }

    T * addElement(T *pElem, int & pIdx)
    {
      _elements.push_back(pElem);
      pIdx = _elements.size()-1;
      return pElem;
    }

    T * getElement(int pId) { return _elements[pId]; }

    void stopThread(int i)  
    {
      if (_stop_f_pt != NULL) 
      {
         ( _elements[i]->*_stop_f_pt)() ;
      }
      pthread_detach(*_threads[i]);
      --_totalRunningThreads;
    }

    void stopAll()  
    {
      if (_stop_f_pt != NULL) 
        for (int i=0; i<_elements.size(); ++i) 
        {
          ( _elements[i]->*_stop_f_pt)() ;
        }
      _totalRunningThreads=0;
    }
};
#endif
// end of test.h
```

// A usage example file "test.cc" that on linux I've compiled with 
The class that incapsulates all the work to thread-ize a method:
g++ -o mytest.exe test.cc -I. -lpthread -lstdc++

```
#include <test.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <Mutex.h>

using namespace std;

// Just a class for which I need to "thread-ize" a some methods
// Given that with OOP the objecs include both "functions" (methods)
// and data (attributes), then there is no need to use function arguments,
// just a "void xxx (void)" method.
// 
class TPuck
{
  public:
   bool _go;
   TPuck(int pVal):_go(true)
   {
     Value = pVal;
   }
   TPuck():_go(true)
   {
   }
   int Value;
   int vc;

   void setValue(int p){Value = p; }

   void super()
   {
     while (_go)
     {
      cout <<"super " << vc << endl;
            sleep(2);
         }
      cout <<"end of super " << vc << endl;
   }

   void vusss()
   {
     while (_go)
     {
      cout <<"vusss " << vc << endl;
      sleep(2);
     }
      cout <<"end of vusss " << vc << endl;
   }

   void fazz()
   {
     static int vcount =0;
     vc = vcount++;
     cout <<"Puck create instance: " << vc << endl;
     while (_go)
     {
       cout <<"fazz " << vc << endl;
       sleep(2);
     }
     cout <<"Completed TPuck..fazz instance "<<  vc << endl;
   }

   void stop()
   {
      _go=false;
      cout << endl << "Stopping TPuck...." << vc << endl;
   }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // just a number of instances of the class I need to make threads
  int vN = 3;

  // This object will be your threads maker.
  // Just declare an instance for each class
  // you need to create method threads
  //
  CSThread<TPuck> PuckThreadMaker;
  //
  // Hera I'm telling which methods should be threaded
  PuckThreadMaker.addThread(&TPuck::fazz, "fazz1");
  PuckThreadMaker.addThread(&TPuck::fazz, "fazz2");
  PuckThreadMaker.addThread(&TPuck::fazz, "fazz3");
  PuckThreadMaker.addThread(&TPuck::vusss, "vusss");
  PuckThreadMaker.addThread(&TPuck::super, "super");

  PuckThreadMaker.addStopMethod(&TPuck::stop);

  for (int ii=0; ii<vN; ++ii)
  {
    // Creating instances of the class that I need to run threads.
    // If you already have your instances, then just pass them as a
    // parameter such "mythreadmaker.addElement(&myinstance);"
    TPuck * vOne = PuckThreadMaker.addElement();
  }

  if (PuckThreadMaker.run() == true)
  {
    cout <<"All running!" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout <<"Error: not all threads running!" << endl;
  }

  sleep(1);
  cout <<"Totale threads creati: " << PuckThreadMaker.runningThreadsCount()  << endl;
  for (unsigned int ii=0; ii<vN; ++ii)
  {
    unsigned int kk=0;
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
  }

  sleep(2);
  PuckThreadMaker.stopAll();
  cout <<"\n\nAfter the stop!!!!" << endl;
  sleep(2);

  for (int ii=0; ii<vN; ++ii)
  {
    int kk=0;
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
    cout <<"status for element " << ii << " is " << PuckThreadMaker.getStatusStr(ii, kk++) << endl; 
  }

  sleep(5);
  return 0;
}

// End of test.cc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old question but a very common issue which many face.
Following is a simple and elegant way to handle this by using std::thread

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class foo
{
    public:
        void bar(int j)
        {
            n = j;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                std::cout << "Child thread executing\n";
                ++n;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            }
        }
        int n = 0;
};

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    foo f;
    std::thread class_thread(&foo::bar, &f, n); // t5 runs foo::bar() on object f
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    std::cout << "Main Thread running as usual";
    class_thread.join();
    std::cout << "Final value of foo::n is " << f.n << '\n';
}
```

Above code also takes care of passing argument to the thread function.

Refer [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) document for more details.

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be this is b/c its getting mangled up a bit by C++ b/c your sending it a C++ pointer, not a C function pointer. There is a [difference](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html) apparently. Try doing a

```
(void)(*p)(void) = ((void) *(void)) &c[0].print; //(check my syntax on that cast)
```

and then sending p.

I've done what your doing with a member function also, but i did it in the class that was using it, and with a **static** function - which i think made the difference.

Comment: I tried the above but its giving me syntax errors.. Tried to change it around as well... If you would be kind enough to show that using the pthread_create(...) it might be helpfull

Answer (score -1):

**[C++ : How to pass class member function to pthread_create()?](http://thispointer.com/c-how-to-pass-class-member-function-to-pthread_create/)**

http://thispointer.com/c-how-to-pass-class-member-function-to-pthread_create/

```
typedef void * (*THREADFUNCPTR)(void *);

class C { 
   // ...
   void *print(void *) { cout << "Hello"; }
}

pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, (THREADFUNCPTR) &C::print, NULL);
```