# The values passed in parameter when creating the lost object when using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, function

My question is regarding the values ​​passed in when creating an object.
Making debugging, it is clear that the values ​​of 'id', 'cont', 'size' and 'nthreads' get lost somehow.
I searched the internet and found the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class) teaching how to pass an object and make a method call him.
It works until the method 'run ()', where the values ​​passed when creating the object are lost.
I do not know if I need to mess with static types so that it does not, however, I am not knowing what to do.

```
class Section1SimpleBarrierThread {

 Section1SimpleBarrierThread(int id, Section1Counter* cont, int size, int nthreads) {
        this->id = id;
        this->cont = cont;
        this->size = size; 
        this->nthreads = nthreads;
  }

  void* run(void){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
       cont->shared_cont++;
       if(cont->shared_cont != this->nthreads) {
         //cont.wait();
       } else {
          //cont->shared_cont = 0;
          // cont.notifyAll();
       }  
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }

  static void* run_helper(void* context){
     return ((Section1SimpleBarrierThread*)context)->run();
  }  
};

while ( (time < TARGETTIME) && (size < MAXSIZE) ){     
j->resetTimer("Section1:Barrier:Simple"); j->startTimer("Section1:Barrier:Simple");

for(int i=0; i<nthreads; i++) { 
thobjectsSimpleBarrierThread[i]= new Section1SimpleBarrierThread(i,cont,size,nthreads);
pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL,&Section1SimpleBarrierThread::run_helper,&thobjectsSimpleBarrierThread[i]);

for(int i=0; i<nthreads; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread_id[i],NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have messed up the braces, maybe it was me when I reformatted the text. Anyway you should double-check them...

Comment: It's all right.
One part is the class definition, the other is a part of the code where I use it.
Thanks for tidying up the formatting, I fumbled at the time.

Comment: It cannot be right because the while part has 3 `{` but only 2 `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'&thobjectsSimpleBarrierThread[i]' - where is this array, and what is its type.  The '&' operator here looks very suspicious...  Surely thobjectsSimpleBarrierThread already a pointer type because you new()ed it on the line above!

Comment: Martin, who did the initial testing now, actually seems to be this problem, I will look more calmly.