# pthread_create in member of class

Tags: c++, oop, class, pthreads, this

Suppose I have the following class:

***.h** :

```
class MyClass{
    void caller();
    int threadProcuder(void *args);
};
```

***cpp** :

```
void MyClass::caller()
{
    pthread_t i;
    pthread_create(&i,NULL,(void*(*)(void*))&MyClass::threadProcedure,(void*)this);
}

int MyClass::threadProcedure(void *args) 
{
    cout << "body of thread" << endl;
}
```

Unforunately, thread doesn't run.

Comment: check error code returned by `pthread_create`

Comment: You've never declared `MyClass::threadProcedure`. The code doesn't compile, nor make sense.

Comment: probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1151582/1025391

Comment: @moooeeeep: Unfortunately in that question the top rated answer is wrong.

Comment: @LokiAstari I know, I left a comment below that answer. Indeed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way is:

```
// Must declare the callback is extern "C" 
// As you are calling back from a C library.
// As this is compiles as C it can only call functions that use the C ABI
// There is no guarantee in the C++ standard that static member functions
// use the same ABI as a "C" function.
//
// Certain C++ ABI definitions do make this explicit but using this knowledge
// Renders your code non portable. If you use a C++ static member it will likely
// break in the future and when it does tracking down the problem will be nearly
// imposable.
extern "C" void* threadProcuder(void *args);

class MyClass{
    void caller();
    void* threadProcuder();
};

void MyClass::caller()
{
    // NOTE: This function should NOT be called from the constructor.
    //       You should really wait until the object is fully constructed
    //       before letting a thread run around inside your object
    //       otherwise the thread may will start playing with members that
    //       are not fully constructed.
    pthread_t i;
    pthread_create(&i,NULL,&threadProcedure,this);
}

void* threadProcuder(void *args)
{
    // I use reinterpret_cast<> here to make it stand out.
    // Others prefer static_cast<>. Both are valid and guaranteed to work.
    // Casting a pointer to/from void* is guaranteed by the standard
    MyClass* obj    = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(args);
    void*    result = NULL;
    try
    {
        result = obj->threadProcuder();
    }
    catch(...) {}   // you MUST catch all exceptions
                    // Failing to do so is very undefined.
                    // In most pthread_application allowing exceptions to escape
                    // usually (but not always) leads to application termination.
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The function passed to `pthread_create` must be declared `extern "C"`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068048/786714 for a better explanation as to why this is the case.

You cannot use a static member-function as my original answer stated, though it may work as it its undefined behavior.

Comment: `static` isn't sufficient.  `pthread_create` is a C function, and takes a pointer to a C function.  The function you pass it has to be `extern "C"`, so it cannot be a member, even `static`.

Comment: You can not use static member functions as the destion of pthread_create. If it happens to be working you are just getting lucky and it is non portable. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6352434/14065

Comment: Oops, I guess I missed that.  I'll edit my answer in a sec.  For those wondering, here's a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068048/786714

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, my format is correct, i didn't call in my constructor.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701766/pedantic-warning-and-pthread-create - your cast of a member function pointer is hiding a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: class MyClass{
static void* threadProcuder(void* param);
}; 
will work in your constructor and any type cast will not be needed

Comment: @ActivationCloud: `Will seem to work`. Technically it is invalid and is non portable. See Michael's comment above and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6352434/14065 Try compiling with -pedantic and the compiler will also warn you about the problem.

Comment: @LokiAstari: can `-pedantic` actually make g++ warn about using a pointer to a static member function with C++ linkage where a C function pointer is required?  I tried it a few days ago hoping to get a warning, but didn't.  Maybe some other `-W` option is necessary?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: O man. I based my comment on your comment on the linked question. I had not actually tried it.

Comment: please tell us how you managed to achieve this @m_pahlevanzadeh

Comment: I explained it in above @moooeeeep