# Why should the thread function of a class be made static to be accessible in the same class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

**My error:**

```
error: cannot convert 'MainWindow::producerThreadFunction' from type 'void* (MainWindow::)(void*)' to type 'void* (*)(void*)'
     if (pthread_create (&producer, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL))
                                                                      ^
```

**Header file:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    pthread_mutex_t mutexVariable = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t  conditionVariable = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    QList <int> queueLIFO;

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    //  This function is run by the thread `Producer`.
    void *producerThreadFunction (void *arg);

    //  This function is run by the thread `Consumer`.
    void *consumerThreadFunction (void *arg);

    int start ();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Source file: (function where the error occurs)**

```
int MainWindow :: start()
{
    pthread_t producer;
    pthread_t consumer;

    if (pthread_create (&producer, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Producer\n");
        return 1;
    }
if (pthread_create (&consumer, NULL, consumerThreadFunction, NULL))
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Consumer\n");
    return 1;
}

if (pthread_join (producer, NULL))
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Producer\n");
    return 2;
}

if (pthread_join (consumer, NULL))
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Consumer\n");
    return 2;
}

return 0;
```

}

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043142/5571184), the solution is to make the `producerThreadFunction` static.

Why should the thread function of a class be made static to be accessible in the same class?

That function is the member function of that class. Why cannot I access it directly?

Comment: Just use standard C++ threads.

Comment: Note while most compilers won't stop you from using a static member function as a "C" function, it's language binding is wrong. And in standard C++ it can't be declared `extern "C"`. I seem to recall that Sun's C++ compiler would warn about it by default.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Good catch - I didn't realize that. I did a little digging and found out that you are correct. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelKoval: I may have been wrong about not possible to declare as `extern "C"`. It appears to be possible for an out-of-class definition. Consequently I posted a [question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037212/static-member-function-with-c-language-binding).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks for opening the question - it's a very interesting discussion. It does appear that static member functions *cannot* be declared `extern "C"`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread_create` expects a function pointer, not a pointer to a member function. These are very different types in C++ because member function pointers include an implicit `this` pointer. In practice, static member functions are equivalent to a non-member function, so that works fine (N.B. this is not technically true according to the standard - see below).

If `pthread` were a C++ library, it would likely take an `std::function` (or, before C++11, a `boost::function`) which can accept a variety of function-like objects; e.g. function pointer, member function pointers, or functor classes. However, since `pthread` is a C library, however, you're stuck writing a static function and manually passing the `this` pointer as an argument.

You should seriously consider using `std::thread` (or, before C++11, `boost::thread`) instead of `pthreads`. The same synchronization primitives are available as are available in `pthreads`, e.g. `std::condition_variable`. The `std::thread` constructor can directly accept a member function pointer:

```
std::thread producer(&MainWindow::producerThreadFunction, this);
```

## The Standard

C and C++ may use different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). This means that it is *not* safe to call a C++ function from C code unless it is wrapped in an [`extern "C"` block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/111426). However, as [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037212/static-member-function-with-c-language-binding) points out, C++11 7.5/4 "Linkage specifications" says:

> A C language linkage is ignored in determining the language linkage of
>   the names of class members and the function type of class member
>   functions.

Therefore, it is not guaranteed to work by the standard. The only standards compliant option is to put the code in a non-member function which, internally, calls a member function:

```
extern "C" {

void producerThreadFunctionWrapper(void *arg)
{
    static_cast<MainWindow *>(arg)->producerThreadFunction();
}

} // extern "C"

// ...

pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, consumerThreadFunctionWrapper, this);
```

## In Practice

In practice, I have never encountered an architecture/compiler where static member functions do not use the C linkage. The answer to [question 33.2 in the C++FQA](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/function.html#fqa-33.2) humorously makes the same point:

> Regarding the static-members-as-callbacks issue: if your
>   implementation uses different binary calling conventions for C
>   functions and C++ static member functions, call the support and inform
>   them that their developers consume mind-altering chemicals at work.

Caveat emptor, however, there are a few reports on StackOverflow (e.g. [in 32 bit Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738313/c-using-class-method-as-a-function-pointer-type/1738425#comment1619007_1738341)) of people being burned by this. The safest option is to use `std::thread` or write an `extern "C"` wrapper for your callbacks.

Comment: The answer is "because pthreads is a C library".  Which is, for many reasons, a Good Thing.

Comment: @paulsm4 I didn't mean to imply that `pthread` *should* be a C++ library - I am quite glad that it is written in C. However, it does make operations like this more verbose. :)

Comment: @MichaelKoval: The answers to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037212/static-member-function-with-c-language-binding) indicate that the static member function will formally always have C++ language linkage, even with `extern "C"` (which is just ignored); hence even if using it as a C callback works in practice with all extant compilers, it's formally Wrong™.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, but would linkage matter when it is called by the pointer from the same translation unit?

Comment: @SergeyA: For calls from C++ no issue. But for calls from C: Formally, it could have a different machine code level calling convention, than expected by the C language code calling it. In practice I think doing things correctly here is mostly about avoiding warnings about the possible formal issue. So it's almost a non-issue, but still it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are almost done with 2015, it is time to throw C++2003 away. The best way to call your thread is following:

```
int MainWindow :: start()
{
    std::thread producer(&MainWindow::producerThreadFunction, this);
    ...
```

See how easy it is? And no need to worry about static member functions at all!

Comment: And for pre C++11 `boost::thread` can be used exactly the same way

Comment: Absent move constructors and rvalue semantics, boost::thread could never be exactly the same.

Comment: Term "exactly" used for this particular case not for usage in general.

Comment: @Slava, with that I do agree.