# g++ error : pthread_create() and pointer to member function

Tags: c++, pthreads, iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pthread Function from a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class)

I am trying to create a thread with a start routine, but g++ does not like my syntax.

```
class myClass
{
  void* myFunction(void* myArg)
  {
    // some code, useless here
  }

  void start()
  {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int* fd;

    //Some code, useless here.

    pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &myFunction, (void*) fd);
  }
}
```

During compilator, g++ tells me that `ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function. Say '&myFunction'`.

It cannot convert `void (myClass::*) (void*)` to `void* (*) (void*)` for argument 3 of `pthread_create`.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to declare myFunction as static for it to be treated as a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regular function member as thread routine. The reason is that such function member requires calling context - `this` object pointer which is unavailable for `pthread` guts.

Make such function member `static` or just free function.

Answer (score 0):

You connot pass a pointer to a non static method. You may want to use a proxy function, passing the pointer to your instance as a parameter to pthread_create and make the myFunction call from there

Answer (score 0):

As compiler said you have to use a static function with pthread, something like this should work :

```
class myClass
{
  static void startThread(void* context)
  {
    ((myClass*)context)->myFunction()
  }

  void myFunction()
  {
    // some code, useless here
  }

  void start()
  {
    pthread_t thread_id;

    //Some code, useless here.

    pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &startThread, this);
  }
}
```

Also you can use a struct as the context in which you can pass this and other arguments if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make your function static, or you can use a little workaround to call the function from your class.

```
void *callMyFunction(void *f)
{
  reinterpret_cast<myClass*>(f)->myFunction();
  return (NULL);
}

class myClass
{
  void* myFunction()
  {
    // some code, useless here
  }

  void start()
  {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int* fd;

    //Some code, useless here.

    pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &callMyFunction, (void*) this);
  }
}
```

If you want to pass parameters to `myClass::myFunction`, you will need to create a little structure like this

```
struct s_param
{
  void  *ptr;
  int   param1;
  char  param2;
  /* other variables */
};
```

`callMyFunction` would become

```
void *callMyFunction(void *bundle)
    {
      reinterpret_cast<myClass*>(bundle->ptr)->myFunction(bundle->param1, bundle->param2/*, ...*/);
      return (NULL);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified by your compiler `pthread_create` expect a `void* (*)(void*)` but you provide a function that has a very similar but different syntax:

Each function of a class that is not `static` has a hidden parameter named `this` of type `class*`, so now your function is `void* (*)( class*, void* )` that is not a match for what expected by `pthread_create`. You should provide a function with same architecture.

Also if you had a function like `void* someFunction()` in your class it could be a match for function that expected by `pthread_create`, of course it is not allowed by compiler and it also has a reason. The reason is calling convention, meaning how parameters passed to a function, C++ compiler allowed to pass `this` in the registers! so it won't match with function that expected by `pthread_create`. This can be solved by some compilers that allow you to select calling convention of your function, but it is not standard, so best approach is to write a proxy function as:

```
static void* my_thread_routine_proxy(void* param) {
    static_cast<my_class*>(param)->my_thread_routine();
}
```

But if you need to pass more parameters you should create an structure for it and pass your parameters in that structure, but do not remember that passed structure must remain valid until your function actually called as a new thread. So it should be a global or dynamically allocated object