# Error while calling function from pthread_create()

Tags: c++, oop, pthreads

I have declared a function in the Class definition inside a header file:

```
class A
{
   public:
   ...
   void* func(void *);
   ...
}
```

In a .C file, I've a pointer to the class A's object as **ptr.**

Now, when i create a pthread:

```
iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, ptr->func, NULL);
```

It throws an error as:
**error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function.**

But when I declare the function **func** as static, this error doesn't come.

I just want to know a workaround for this as I can't change the function to static since I can't call other non-static members from it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pthread Function from a Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460219/attaching-member-function-of-a-class-in-pthread and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12975232/981959 and dozens of others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use non-static member functions as thread functions, or as functions to any non-C++ function expecting a function pointer. The reason is that all non-static member function has a hidden first argument that becomes the `this` pointer.

In this case it can be solved with a static proxy-function:

```
class A
{
public:
    void* func();

    static void* wrapper(void* object)
        { return reinterpret_cast<A*>(object)->func(); }
};

...

A* ptr = new A;
iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &A::wrapper, ptr);
```

This will create the thread with `A::wrapper` as the thread function, and pass the instance pointer as argument. The `A::wrapper` function then uses this argument as a pointer to the instance, and calls the real function.

---

However, if you have a C++11 capable compiler and standard library, there are much better support for [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread):

```
A myA;
std::thread myThread(&A::func, &myA);
```

The above object creation creates a thread that will call `A::func` and pass the hidden first argument to the function as it needs.