# using pthread in class using c++

Tags: c++, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pthread Function from a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class)

Can anyone give a simple example so I can understand how to use pthread in class?

The examples in Internet are so complicated that I don't get the concept.

I have written a code when not using class.

Edit:

I need to compile something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
using namespace std;
class test
{
private:
    int i = 0;
public:

static void *fun()
{
    i = i+1;
    cout << i<< endl;
}
};

int main()
{
pthread_t th;
test newTest;
pthread_create(&th, NULL, newTest.fun, NULL);
}
```

Comment: You are sure you don't want to use `std::thread` of C++11 instead?

Comment: You need a simple POSIX threads tutorial.

Comment: There is really no difference in using pthread with or without classes. These are completely orthogonal concepts. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: If your concern is passing the `this` pointer to member functions, see the example at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class

Comment: C++11 is experimental so I prefer not to use it.

Comment: @HamedJML Of course there can be reasons against using C++11, notably the fact that compiler support is extremely inconsistent for some of the new features. Nevertheless, I wouldn't call it _Experimental_. The C++11 is the most up to date, officially released version of the C++ Standard.

Comment: Would you give me a link about using thread in C++11?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class