# use g_thread_new with a struct

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gdk

I want to start a struct method in an own thread:

```
g_thread_new( "NewThread", mymethod , NULL)
```

The problem is, the program only compiles if I set the method to "static":

```
static gpointer mymethod(gpointer nrp) { puts(this->mystring) ; ... }
```

But if I set the method to "static" I cannot access the struct instance variables like this->mystring.

Is there a way to use g_thread_new with class methods AND access instance variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pthread Function from a Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class)

Comment: Which instance's variables are you expecting to access? You haven't selected an instance.

Comment: What's going on, we literally had the same question [five minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18818156/596781)?

Comment: Hello @DavidSchwartz, you mean I could handle a kind of a pointer with the thread pointing to the instance that I want to deal with? Can I then overwrite the this-> - field?

Comment: @Kenobi Exactly. You pass a pointer to the instance to the thread and then the thread can invoke a member function on that instance, causing the member function's `this` pointer to point to the correct instance.

Answer (score 0):

What you can and should do is receive a `void*` in your static function as a parameter from the thread. That `void*` is the object that you want it's function called. Just cast it to the object's type and call the method.

Also, consider using `boost::thread`.

Comment: That sounds promising... I now use a workaround for that problem, but I'll consider your answer when I finally throw out the workaround. One question - will this void* object help me access class variables or will it prevent me to having to put the method to static?