# pthread to run method of instances of a class in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a `Drone` class, which is basically a pair of integers `(x, y)` for its location in a 2D  cartesian plane, and prints its location while moving one step at once towards its destination `(dest_x, dest_y)`.

I am doing this in

```
void * run(void);
```

method, which takes care of launching, moving, avoiding collision with other `Drone`s.

The instances of `Drone`s are stored in `vector<Drone*> drones`, which is a global variable.

When I initialized the `Drone`s and ran `run()` sequentially, it printed out the result correctly.

For example,

```
location: (0, 0)
.
.
location: (5, 5)
Warning: drone 1 and 0may collide. Running collision avoidance.
.
.
location: (15, 22)
location: (15, 23)
drone 0 successfully served its delivery request.
returning to the control center...
location: (14, 22)
location: (13, 21)
.
.
location: (0, 0)
```

With

```
Drone* d = new Drone(0);
d->set_loc(0, 0);
d->set_dest(15, 23);
drones.push_back(d);
.
.
drones[0]->run();
drones[1]->run();
```

However, I wanted to run this in parallel, i.e. the `Drone`s are moving concurrently, not one moving after another one finishes moving.

For this, I defined a helper class ([pthread function from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class)),

```
static void* run_helper(void * context) {
    return ((Drone *)context)->run();
}
```

and tried passing it to `pthread_create()` like

```
pthread_t t[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, &Drone::run_helper, &drones[i]);
}
```

It runs without an error, but it does not print anything.

Does anyone see what is wrong in my code?

Thank you.

---

UPDATE:

I added

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    pthread_join(t[i], NULL);
}
```

to the end of the main function, and now it prints something, but a very strange one

```
Warning: drone drone_id: 82002080 location: ( and 08200272, may collide. Running collision avoidance.8200271)

drone_id: 8200208 location: (0, 8200270)
Warning: drone 0 and 8200270may collide. Running collision avoidance.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

(I don't know why the drone id is so big. I initialized them with 0 and 1)

Should I join the thread?

If so, am I doing this wrong?(for example, should `vector<Drone*> drones` be a mutually exclusive resource?)

Comment: compile command is: g++ decoy.cpp -lpthread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in this line

```
pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, &Drone::run_helper, &drones[i]);
```

You pass an address of the pointer (`Drone**`) and cast to pointer (`Drone*`). So change it to

```
pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, &Drone::run_helper, (void*)(drones[i]));
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. The first several lines are printed like `drone_id: drone_id: 01 location: ( location: (16, , 6)1)`
 instead of `drone_id: 0 location: (1, 1) drone_id: 1 location: (6, 6)`. I know what it is, but do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @user2418202 You need to use [mutex](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes) to synchronize your output. For example, when you get to print function use `pthread_mutex_lock` then do the output and then use `pthread_mutex_unlock`. Note that mutex object should be one for every thread you want to synchronize.