# Can't figure out syntax to call multiple object functions as separate threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have an array of objects and want each one to call a member function in a separate thread (so they run concurrently).  I'm using `_beginthreadex` and can get it to work fine for a standard function but can't figure out the syntax to pass the member function to the `_beginthreadex` call.  Here's an example of what I'm doing (the block of code after the second comment does not compile):

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <process.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    unsigned __stdcall mythread(void* data) { 
        printf("\nThread %d", GetCurrentThreadId()); 
        return 0; 
    }

    class myClass {
        public:
            unsigned __stdcall myClass::myThread(void* data);
    };

    unsigned __stdcall myClass::myThread(void* data) {
        printf("\nThread %d", GetCurrentThreadId()); 
        return(0);
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

        int i, numThreads = 5;

        // this works
        HANDLE *myHandle = new HANDLE[numThreads];
        for(i=0;i<numThreads;i++) myHandle[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythread, 0, 0, 0);
        WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, myHandle, true, INFINITE); 
        for(i=0;i<numThreads;i++) CloseHandle(myHandle[i]); 
        getchar();
        delete myHandle;

        // this does not compile - not sure of syntax to call myObject[i].myThread in _beginthreadex
        HANDLE *myHandle2 = new HANDLE[numThreads];
        myClass *myObject = new myClass[numThreads];
        for(i=0;i<numThreads;i++) myHandle2[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &myObject[i].myThread, 0, 0, 0);
        WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, myHandle2, true, INFINITE); 
        for(i=0;i<numThreads;i++) CloseHandle(myHandle2[i]);  
        getchar();
        delete myObject;
        delete myHandle2;

        return 0; 
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

rgames

Comment: The problem you are seeing is pretty much the same one as described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You cannot get address of member fuinction using

  ```
  &myObject[i].myThread
  ```

  correct way is like this

  ```
  &myClass::myThread
  ```
- In C++ functions and member functions have different signature like

  ```
  /* pointer for this function would have type void(*)(int, float)  */
  void foo(int, float) { /* ... */ }

  class A {
  public:
      /* pointer for this function would have type void(A::*)(int, float)  */
      void foo(int, float) { /* ... */ }
  };
  ```

  they are have different type even they both return `void` and take `int` and `float`.

As you can see in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) the `_beginthread` function takes function as

```
unsigned (__stdcall *)( void * )
```

but you are trying to pass

```
unsigned (__stdcall myClass::*)( void* )
```

So to correct your code you can do:

**Method 1:** you need to write another function, something like

```
unsigned __stdcall mymemberthread(void* data) {
    if (data != NULL) {
        myClass* m = (myClass*)data;
        m->myThread(m + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And create thread like

```
(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mymemberthread, &myObject[i], 0, 0);
```

**Method 2:** make function `myClass::myThread` `static`

```
class myClass {
    public:
        static unsigned __stdcall myThread(void* data);
};
unsigned __stdcall myClass::myThread(void* data) {
    printf("\nThread %d", GetCurrentThreadId());
    if (data != NULL) {
        myClass* m = (myClass*)data;
        m->myThread(m + 1);
    }
    return(0);
}
...
(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &myClass::myThread, &myObject[i], 0, 0);
```

**Method 3:** if this is acceptabe use STL and `std::thread`, this will make you code more generic.

Comment: Bravo!  I used your Method 1 and it appears to do the trick.  Thanks for the assistance!