# how to get the function pointer to a function in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a function in C:

```
void start_fun()
{
   // do something
}
```

I want to use `pthread_create()` to create a thread and the start routine is `start_fun()`, without modifing `void start_fun()`, how to get the function pointer to `start_fun()`;

Comment: `start_fun` *is* the pointer to `start_fun`. Although.. it isn't a function of the correct type. `pthread_create` wants a `void * (*f) (void *)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write the function name `start_fun` without any parameters anywhere in your code, you will get a function pointer to that function.

*However* pthread_create expects a function of the format `void* func (void*)`.

If rewriting the function isn't an option, you'll have to write a wrapper:

```
void* call_start_fun (void* dummy)
{
  (void)dummy;

  start_fun();

  return 0;
}
```

then pass call_start_fun to pthread_create:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, call_start_fun, NULL);
```

Comment: The function isn't of the correct type required by `pthread_create`.

Comment: @ArjunShankar Indeed, I've fixed the answer. Thank you.

Comment: It's just a matter of style, but I would return `NULL`  from `call_start_fun`

Comment: @JeremyP Doesn't matter since the result will be [any null pointer constant] casted to void* and the function will therefore always return the null pointer constant `(void*)0`.

Comment: yes, but I got a error error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'void* (*)(void*)' [-fpermissive]
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, start_fun, NULL);

Comment: @ratzip Then compile the above code instead, which solves the problem?

Comment: no, I do not want to change the function of start_fun()

Comment: @ratzip, the pthread start function *must* have the signature that both @Lundin and I specified.  The signature of `pthread_create()` demands it, and your program has undefined behavior that likely involves crashing or memory corruption if you do not provide it.

Comment: I try your code, I put the wrapper function as a public function in C++ class, then I got the following:
error: cannot convert 'TryTest::call_start_fun' from type 'void* (TryTest::)(void*)' to type 'void* (*)(void*)'
TryTest is the class name

Comment: @ratzip You tagged your question C. And that problem is not likely related to the format of the function, but more likely because it is a C++ member function. You'll most likely have to declare the function as `static` in order to pass it to pthread_create.

Comment: @ratzip [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class).

Comment: @Lundin That's why I said it is just a matter of style, but I would use `NULL` rather than 0 because the return value is meant to be a pointer and you don't want people putting things like `return 1` because they assume it's like `main()`

Comment: @JeremyP That wouldn't work, `1` doesn't convert to `void *`.

Comment: @unwind Clang compiles it and emits a warning.

Comment: @JeremyP Oh. That's ... worse than I expected, but of course a warning is a pretty good indicator that "people" are doing something wrong. :) I'd use `NULL` too personally, btw.

Comment: @unwind The kind of person to use `return 1` when the function is meant to return a `void*` is also the kind of person who would ignore compiler warnings IMO :)

Answer (score 3):

The function name, used as an expression, evaluates to a pointer to the named function.  Thus, for instance:

```
pthread_t thread_id;
int result = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, start_fun, NULL);
```

**HOWEVER**, the start function you present does not have the correct signature, therefore using it *as* a pthread start function produces undefined behavior.  The start function must have this signature:

```
void *start_fun(void *arg);
```

The function may ignore its argument and always return `NULL`, if appropriate, but it must be declared with both the argument and the return value (of those types).