# Why does pthread_create not take my method within the same class?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I want to spawn a thread from within my class but can't seem to find the correct formula to make `pthread_create()` happy.

My class looks like:

```
#ifndef _BFD_ENDPOINT_H_
#define _BFD_ENDPOINT_H_
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

enum BfdState_e {
        BFD_STAT_ADMIN_DOWN = 0,
        BFD_STAT_DOWN,
        BFD_STAT_INIT,
        BFD_STAT_UP };


class BfdEndpoint {
   public:
        int RxIntvlSet(int);
        int TxIntvlSet(int);
        int MultSet(int);
        int ActvSet(bool);
        enum BfdState_e StatusGet();
        BfdEndpoint();  // constructor
        ~BfdEndpoint(); // destructor

   public:
        //configuration params
        int rx;         // Rx interval [us]
        int tx;         // Tx interval [us]
        int mult;       // multiplier
        bool active;    // active (1) or passive (0) endpoint
        //internal vars
        enum BfdState_e status;
        pthread_t *RxTh;
        pthread_t *TxTh;
        //internal methods
        int Start();
        void *RxSM(void);
        void *TxSM(void);

};
#endif
```

and the implementation of the respective function looks like:

```
void *BfdEndpoint::RxSM(void)
{
        return NULL;
}

int BfdEndpoint::Start(void)
{
        int rv = 0;
        rv = pthread_create(RxTh,NULL,&BfdEndpoint::RxSM,NULL);

}
```

and `g++` is barking the following:

```
$ g++ *.cpp -o bfd
bfd.cpp: In member function ‘int BfdEndpoint::Start()’:
bfd.cpp:34:55: error: cannot convert ‘void* (BfdEndpoint::*)()’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
  rv = pthread_create(RxTh,NULL,&BfdEndpoint::RxSM,NULL);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `_BFD_ENDPOINT_H_` is a reserved identifier (because it starts with underscore followed by uppercase). You should come up with another name for the include guard.

Comment: You're run afoul of the hidden `this` parameter all member functions have. `void *RxSM(void);` looks to the compiler more like `void *RxSM(BfdEndpoint*);`

Comment: No, identifiers that contain two consecutive underscore are also reserved. `BFD_ENDPOINT_H_` would be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pthread function from a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem1: `pthread_create` expects a function that takes a `void*` as an argument. Your function doesn't accept a `void*` argument.

Problem2: `pthread_create` expects a *function pointer*. Applying address-of operator on a non-static member function results in a *member function pointer*. A member function pointer is not convertible to a regular function pointer.

Solution: Use a callback function that matches the function pointer signature that `pthread_create` expects. This means that you must use a free function (or a static member function).

You can call a member function on an object within that free function. A trivial example:

```
void* RxSM(void*) {
    static BfdEndpoint object;
    object.RxSM();
}
```

You may wish to call `BfdEndpoint::RxSM` on the object that created the thread instead. You can pass that object to the callback by using the fourth `void *arg` argument.

Comment: Interesting take on the lazy loader, but how does the code call `BfdEndpoint::Start` to set up the `pthread` in the first place?

Comment: @user4581301 you'd have to do that on another object. If OP wishes to call `BfdEndpoint::RxSM` on the same object that created the thread, then they will have to do some work and develop this further.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_create` only accepts regular function pointers (or compatible) to create a thread. It is a limitation of a `C` compatible interface

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

The C++11 thread abstraction interface does support class member functions to be run as a thread. Of course a member function requires a pointer to an actual object (`this` pointer), so you will have to pass that to the `thread` object

```
BfdEndpoint object;
std::thread thr{&BfdEndpoint::memfunc, &object, ...};
```