# C++ boost thread causes segmentation fault when instantiated twice

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a class which runs a background task when it is constructed (see the constructor). This task is then stopped and the thread is joined in the destructor when the object is destroyed:

```
// Foo.hpp -------------------------------
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time.hpp>

class Foo {
  boost::thread theThread;

  Foo();
  ~Foo();
  void bar() const;
}

// Foo.cpp -------------------------------
// This is the background task.
void Foo::bar() const {
  while (true) {
    try {
      // sleep for 1 minute.
      boost:this_thread_sleep(boost::posix_time::minutes(1));

      // do other stuff endlessly
    }

    // boost interrupt was called, stop the main loop.
    catch (const boost::thread_interrupted&)
    {
      break;
    }
}

// Instantiate background task
Foo::Foo()
    : theThread(&Foo::bar, this)
{
    // do other stuff
}

// Stop background task
Foo::~Foo() {
    theThread.interrupt()
    theThread.join();
}
```

Now this works fine when I have a single instance to the class:

```
// main.cpp
Foo f;
// do other stuff with f
```

But when I do this I get a segmentation fault and an aborted message:

```
// main.cpp
Foo *f;
f = new Foo(); // causes seg fault
delete f;
```

Why?

Comment: Does `boost::thread` attempt to dereference the second parameter in its constructor (in your case, `this`)?  If so, then using `this` as an argument in your initialization list doesn't seem to be safe.

Comment: Not sure if foo::bar is constructed yet when you give it to the thread

Comment: Sorry, but your code does not compile and your destructor is private so you cannot instantiate this class in main.cpp. Are you sure this code reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode gives the error:

> Attempting to use a deleted function

Foo::Bar is not callable with the syntax above(&Foo::Bar), since it is not a static function. It has a hidden this parameter which causes the signatures not to match.

More on this here:
[pthread function from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class)

Also it is bad practice to use member functions on initializer lists, the behavior is undefined. Quoted here:

> Member functions (including virtual member functions) can be called
>   from member initializers, but the behavior is undefined if not all
>   direct bases are initialized at that point.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

The following works:

```
   void bar(atomic_int*exit) {
    while (*exit) {
        // sleep for 1 minute.
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

        // do other stuff endlessly

    }
}

class Foo {
    thread theThread;
    atomic_int _exit;

public:
   // Instantiate background task
    Foo(): _exit(1)
    {
        // do other stuff
        init();
    }
    void init()
    {
        theThread = std::thread (&bar,&_exit);
    }

    // Stop background task
    ~Foo() {
        _exit = 0;
        theThread.join();
    }
};
```

Comment: No std::thread or atomic types in my c++ version, sorry bro, doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I don't use boost but it does have boost::atomic<int>  if you wish to look further. In any case you can't pass the member function this way need to externalize it or make it static.