# How to use dedicated thread class MyThreadClass

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, pthreads

I've fond `MyThreadClass` in this article: [pthread function from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class) and would like to use it in my class but I'm struggling to figure it out, what I have by now is:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define OK      0
#define ERROR   -1

//-- ThreadClass
class MyThreadClass
{
public:
   MyThreadClass() {/* empty */}
   virtual ~MyThreadClass() {/* empty */}

   /** Returns true if the thread was successfully started, false if there was an error starting the thread */
   bool StartInternalThread()
   {
      return (pthread_create(&_thread, NULL, InternalThreadEntryFunc, this) == 0);
   }

   /** Will not return until the internal thread has exited. */
   void WaitForInternalThreadToExit()
   {
      (void) pthread_join(_thread, NULL);
   }

protected:
   /** Implement this method in your subclass with the code you want your thread to run. */
   virtual void InternalThreadEntry() = 0;

private:
   static void * InternalThreadEntryFunc(void * This) {
       ((MyThreadClass *)This)->InternalThreadEntry(); return NULL;
       }

   pthread_t _thread;
};
//-- /ThreadClass
//--- DUMMY DECLARATIONS BELOW TO MAKE IT COMPILE ---//
#define LOG_NS_ERROR std::cout
class test{
    public:
        int get_child(std::string x){return OK;};
};
test *_global;
typedef struct test_struct{} _db_transact;
class db_transact{
    public: 
        db_transact(int,int&,int&){};
};
int _ns;
int _log_id;
//--- DUMMY DECLARATIONS ABOVE TO MAKE IT COMPILE ---//
class db_c_hndlr : public MyThreadClass{
    public: 
        db_c_hndlr(void);
        ~db_c_hndlr(void);
        db_transact *db_conn_get(void);
        void InternalThreadEntry(void *func);
    private:
        int _stop;
        std::vector<db_transact*> _db_pool;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------

db_c_hndlr::db_c_hndlr(void) {
}
//---------------------------------------------------------

void db_c_hndlr::InternatThreadEntry(void *func) {

    while(!stop){
        std::cout << "going!" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------

db_c_hndlr::~db_c_hndlr() {
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<db_transact*>::iterator it;
    for (i=0, it = _db_pool.begin();it!=_db_pool.end();it++, i++) {
        if (_db_pool[i])
            if (_db_pool[i]!=NULL) 
                delete _db_pool[i];
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------

db_transact *db_c_hndlr::db_conn_get(void) {
    db_transact *tmp;

    tmp = new db_transact(_global->get_child("db_config"), _ns, _log_id);
    _db_pool.push_back(tmp);
    return tmp;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    db_transact *conn=NULL;
    db_c_hndlr db;
    //db = new db_c_hndlr();

    conn= db.db_conn_get();
    return OK;
}
```

but I get a compiler mesage that looks like:

```
$ g++ -lpthread pseudo_code.cpp 
pseudo_code.cpp:70:48: error: no ‘void db_c_hndlr::InternatThreadEntry(void*)’ member function declared in class ‘db_c_hndlr’
 void db_c_hndlr::InternatThreadEntry(void *func) {
                                                ^
pseudo_code.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
pseudo_code.cpp:101:16: error: cannot declare variable ‘db’ to be of abstract type ‘db_c_hndlr’
     db_c_hndlr db;
                ^
pseudo_code.cpp:54:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘db_c_hndlr’:
 class db_c_hndlr : public MyThreadClass{
       ^
pseudo_code.cpp:29:17: note:    virtual void MyThreadClass::InternalThreadEntry()
    virtual void InternalThreadEntry() = 0;
```

and I'm struggling to figure out how I can get it to work.

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: @DrewDormann yes it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in the presented code that result in the errors reported.

1. `InternatThreadEntry` is not a member of `db_c_hndlr` because `db_c_hndlr` declares `InternalThreadEntry`. This is just a simple typo: Interna**t** != Interna**l**.
2. `db_c_hndlr` is an abstract class because the pure virtual function `InternalThreadEntry` declared in `MyThreadClass` had no parameters.

```
virtual void InternalThreadEntry() = 0;
```

is not implemented by

```
void InternalThreadEntry(void *func)
```

in `db_c_hndlr`. It looks like `void *func` should not be needed, so I'd solve this by removing the parameter.

Unrelated: You may find [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) more versatile and portable.