# C++ callback functions in class Referention to non-static funct

Tags: c++, callback

I have that code and want to modify it and put it in class for example MergeSort

after I convert it to class I get an error in that line in initMergeSort:

> error: no matches converting function ‘merge_sort’ to type ‘void* (*)(void*)’
>            if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, merge_sort, (void *) NULL) != 0) {
>
> Referention to non-static function must be called (possible target for call
>
> {Clion recognize it *merge_sort})

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, merge_sort,(void *) NULL);
```

1. The way I want to make it:

New header

```
and the new header:
```

```
    class MergeSort {
       private:
       //int *notSortedData;
       int *sortedData{};
       int part = 0;
       void merge(int low, int mid, int high);

       void merge_sort(int low, int high);
       //Problem is here: --v
       void *merge_sort(void *arg);


       public:
       MergeSort(int* notSortedData){
           this->sortedData = notSortedData;
       }
       static const int MAX = 20;
       static const int HALF_OF_MAX = MAX / 2;
       int initMergeSort(/*int *notSortedData*/);
};
```

old header:

```
    static const int MAX = 20 ;
    static const int HALF_OF_MAX = MAX / 2;

    void merge(int low, int mid, int high);
    void merge_sort(int low, int high);
    void *merge_sort(void *arg);
    int initMergeSort(int *notSortedData);
```

2. old implementation:

```
    // array of size MAX
    int *a;
    int part;
    void merge(int low, int mid, int high) {(...)}

// merge sort function

    void merge_sort(int low, int high) {
        // calculating mid point of array
        (...)
          // calling first half
          merge_sort(low, mid);
          // calling second half
          merge_sort(mid + 1, high);
          // merging the two halves
          merge(low, mid, high);
    }
}
```

// thread function for multi-threading Problem is here

----------------------v

```
    void *merge_sort(void *arg) {
    // which part out of 4 parts
    int thread_part = part++;

    // calculating low and high
    int low = thread_part * (MAX / 4);
    int high = (thread_part + 1) * (MAX / 4) - 1;

    // evaluating mid point
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if (low < high) {
        merge_sort(low, mid);
        merge_sort(mid + 1, high);
        merge(low, mid, high);
    }
}

// merge function for merging two parts

    int initMergeSort(int *notSortedData) {
    a = notSortedData;
    (...)
    pthread_t threads[THREAD_MAX];

    // creating 4 threads Here I have to invoke function call merge_sort
    for (unsigned long &thread : threads) {
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, merge_sort,
                       (void *) NULL);
    }
    // joining all 4 threads
    (...)
    // merging the final 4 parts
    merge(0, (HALF_OF_MAX - 1) / 2, HALF_OF_MAX - 1);
    (...) 
}
```

Thank you for in advance

Full old code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Bzahov98/bc97bc5700319cae9f3846c09ac8d70c), and Full code after my unsuccesful refactor is [here](https://gist.github.com/Bzahov98/d5159126390fe64c22b39941d5c90a82):

Comment: Are you forced to use `pthread`s? [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) in C++11 and beyond make this pretty much a non-problem.

Comment: If `std::thread` is not an option, consider this alternative: [pthread function from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class)

Comment: The error message explicitly points to the problem: the signature of your `merge_sort` function doesn't match the expected by `pthread_create`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a non-static class method for a pthread callback.  A non-static method has a hidden `this` parameter that pthread won't be able to account for when calling the method.

You need to use a static method instead (or a non-member function), eg:

```
class MergeSort {
   private:
   ...
   static void* static_merge_sort(void *arg);
   void* merge_sort();
};
```

```
void* MergeSort::static_merge_sort(void *arg)
{
    return ((MergeSort*)arg)->merge_sort();
}

void* MergeSort::merge_sort()
{
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &MergeSort::static_merge_sort, this);
```

Comment: thank you I did a little different on the base of your code: (CLion ide proposal me some edits to make it compile)       ` void *MergeSort::static_merge_sort(void *arg) {
    return static_cast<void *>(((MergeSort *) arg)->merge_sortCallback());`
}